# How to make a query for a html select form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Here is my html select form.

```
<select name='md' multiple="yes" size="10">
                <optgroup label="Оpel">
                    <option value="Astra" name='Ast'>Astra</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Nissan">        
                    <option value="Pulsar" name='Puls'>Pulsar</option>
                    <option value="Almera" name='Alm'>Almera</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Honda">
                    <option value="Civic" name='Civ'>Civic</option>
                                 </optgroup>     
                                 <optgroup label="Audi">
                    <option value="Q7" name='Q'>Q7</option>                 
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="BMW">
                    <option value="M3" name='M'>M3</option>
                    </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Renault">
                                        <option value="Megane" name='Meg'>Megane</option>
                    </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Mercedes">
                                        <option value="G-Class" name='G'>G-Class</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
$md = (isset($_POST['md']));
```

How i should make my query so when user choose a option from the select menu to call all rows from the table who match with the choosen option.

HERE IS MY WHOLE QUERY where i need to add the select field as a variable for searching by the users.

```
 $sql = "
 SELECT c.brand
      , c.model
      , c.reg_num
      , c.horse_powers
      , c.color
      , u.first_name
      , u.last_name 
   FROM cars c
   JOIN clients_cars uc 
     ON c.id = uc.cars_id 
   JOIN clients u
     ON uc.clients_id = u.id 
  WHERE c.id IN (   SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id 
                               FROM clients_cars 
                              WHERE rent_date BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' 
                                 OR return_date BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' 
                                 OR ((return_date>'$d2')AND(rent_date<'$d1')) 
                                 OR ((horse_powers > '$hp1') AND (horse_powers < '$hp2'))
                   )
  ";
```

Should it be like this or i'm wrong ?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%$md%';
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: With your query, if the user chooses "Astra" option, you will get all the rows with column1 containing "Astra" (could be only "Astra" or "Opel Astra" or "somethingbefore Astrasomethingafter"). Is that what you need? By the way, `option` tags don't need a `name` attribute. ;)

Comment: If $md is set, than it will be an array, so you'll need a loop to not only search for the first element like caCtus said.

Comment: well my query is a little more complicated and i need to add this select field to my query too. But when i add it this way its doesn't work normally. I will edit my question with the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ajax for this implementation,

```
$('#id_of_select').change(function(){

    $value = $(this).val();
    $.post('new_php_file.php',{md:$value},function(response){
        alert(response);
    })

});
```

new_php_file.php :

```
<?php
    $md = $_POST['md'];
    //You can use it now as you wanted...like SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%$md%'; Just dont forget to echo your result.      
?>
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Without Ajax :

I'm supposing that you are working in index.php

HTML :

```
<form method="POST"> <!-- No need to set action parameter -->
    <select name='md' multiple="yes" size="10">
    ..
    ..
    <input type="submit" value="Click to Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP :

in same index.php file,

```
 <?php

      if(isset($_POST['md']))
      {
          $md = $_POST['md']; 

         // Your business logic here

      }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without ajax ?